# Examples of automated testing in a CRUD Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, crud

I have a web application that is mostly CRUD but also has some business logic.
I am using ORM (Entity Framework) with Domain, Service and UI (ASP.NET MVC) layers.

I am looking to add automated testing for this application.

Are there some Open source applications which demonstrate best practices on doing:

- Unit Tests
- Integration Tests
- UI Tests

within one application.

There are plenty of code examples of very simple cases, but what about a "non-simple" application that is used in real world.

Answer (score 1):

I ll describe what I m doing here but dont assume this is the right way of doing it - just describing my experience:

I use NUnit to write all my unit tests for my Data Access layer using an SQLite db to "mock" the database. This way all database calls are real but the db is in memory so you can still achieve a good performance when running your tests. Every data access method should be tested thoroughly here.

My business functionality is tested again using NUnit but using Moq to mock all data access operations. If you are caching anything in your business tier (like I do) you can inject an In-Memory Cache class instead of your real one to make sure stuff are put in the cache correctly.

Although many people like doing that for their controllers I prefer to use a frontend testing tool like Selenium to "record" my unit-tests and convert them to code subsequently. Selenium is a great tool at testing real-world functionality and not just a certain case in isolation to the rest. You can use the relevant Firefox plugin to record all major functionality in your system and plan your assertions (e.g. click on button A takes me to page B where I can see my "Thank you" message). Selenium is a great tool to run automated frontend unit-tests as well. You can either convert your tests into C# code and run them through your Continuous integration tool of choice during your nightly builds (I use TeamCity and works great), or alternatively, depending on the size of your app, there are several web apps that take your selenium scripts as the input and run them in a semi-automated fashion.

Just to clarify: it's nice to have all those tests above (data access, business tier, front-end tests) as NUnit tests and setup a simple CI tool to run them every night. This way you know if something breaks the moment you commit some code in or every morning that you get in the office.

Sorry this isn't the example you were looking for but I thought it could help you out.